# Bigquery - Delete duplicate rows in tables by rank()

Tags: google-bigquery

We used ETL to synchronize data from cloud storage to Bigquery, just appended latest data to table.

There're might be updated data with same attribute but with different processing timestamp. We just want to keep the latest record in the table.

Due to there's no primary concept inn Bigquery, cannot do upsert action. We want to delete redundant data by applying ranking window function.

We're able to use `CREATE OR RELACE` method to recreate table with latest information. However, there're over 200GB records in this table, wanna know if we can simply delete useless data?

here's our sample table schema and data,

```
create table `project.dataset.sample`
(
  name string,
  process_timestamp timestamp not null,
  amount int
)
PARTITION BY
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(process_timestamp, DAY);


insert into `project.dataset.sample`
values
('Zoe', timestamp('2022-07-09 05:04:13.439780+00'),1 ),
('Zoe', timestamp('2022-07-09 10:53:13.330751+00'),2 ),
('Zoe', timestamp('2022-07-09 18:48:01.089188+00'),3 ),
('Zoe', timestamp('2022-07-10 11:06:01.053347+00'),4 ),
('Zoe', timestamp('2022-07-10 19:11:17.731549+00'),5 ),
('Tess', timestamp('2022-07-10 11:06:01.053347+00'),1 ),
('Tess', timestamp('2022-07-10 19:11:17.731549+00'),2 )
```

We expected there're two record left after executing the delete SQL,
however, it deleted all record...

```
DELETE
FROM `project.dataset.sample` ori
WHERE EXISTS ( 
  WITH dedup as (select *, 
       rank() over(partition by name order by process_timestamp desc) as rank
       from `project.dataset.sample` 
  )
  SELECT * FROM r
  WHERE ori.name = dedup.name and dedup.rank > 1);
```

Is there any method to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, update SQL as below

```
DELETE
FROM `project.dataset.sample` ori
WHERE EXISTS ( 
  WITH dedup as (select *, 
       rank() over(partition by name order by process_timestamp desc) as rank
       from `project.dataset.sample` 
  )
  SELECT * except(rank) 
  FROM dedup
  WHERE ori.name = dedup.name
    and ori.process_timestamp = dedup.process_timestamp
    and dedup.rank > 1
);
```